# Tablas y gráficas no se cargan en un segundo tab

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Estoy usando las pestañas (*tab*) de Bootstrap. Tengo dos y en el segundo tab estoy usando DataTable y Chart, pero no funcionan. En el primer tab funciona bien, leí algo sobre que los elementos del segundo tab están escondidos por eso no aplica, pero no estoy seguro, a ver si algún compañero sepa la solución.

Éste es un ejemplo de mi código HTML (reducido):

```
<div role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
  <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2">Tab1</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="tab1">
  <canvas id="grafica" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
<div id="tab2">
  <canvas id="grafica" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
</div>
```

Los tabs funcionan bien y paso de uno a otro sin problema, al final del código estoy agregando ChartJS y DataTable, y eso funciona bien en el primer tab. En el segundo es como si no hubiera agregado nada de Chart y DataTable.

Éste es mi código JS:

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){

    var datos = {
      labels : ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
      datasets : [{
        label : "2017",
        backgroundColor : "rgb(26,187,156)",
        data : [12.500, 11.900, 12.000, 10.100, 12.300, 12.000, 11.200, 10.150, 10.602, 12.000, 12.010, 12.992]
      },


    ]};


    var canvas = document.getElementById('grafica').getContext('2d');
    window.bar = new Chart(canvas, {
      type : "bar",
      data : datos,
      options : {
        elements : {
          rectangle : {
            borderWidth : 1,

            borderSkipped : 'bottom'
          }
        },
        responsive : true,
        title : {
          display : true,
          text : "2017"
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Como puse arriba todo funciona bien en el primer tab, la gráfica se muestra y el DataTable funciona. El problema es el segundo tab, que no funciona nada en ese. ¿Por qué puede ser?¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que no se entiende de la pregunta? Parece estar bastante clara y el problema (y la solución) se pueden ver en el código compartido. Quizás le falle algo el formato y sería mejor si hubiera un [mcve], pero parece entenderse el problema bien.

Answer (score -2):

Efectivamente tu problema esta en que estas repitiendo el id="grafica" para ambos canvas.
Si bien uno esta oculto y el otro no, en el DOM se renderizan ambos por lo tanto javascript solo aplica al primero que aparezca y no a los dos.

```
       <div role="tabpanel" data-example-id="togglable-tabs">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs bar_tabs" role="tablist">
      <li><a href="#tab1">Tab1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#tab2">Tab1</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="tab1">
      <canvas id="grafica" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2">
       <canvas id="grafica2" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>


 <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){

    var datos = {
      labels : ["Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"],
      datasets : [{
        label : "2017",
        backgroundColor : "rgb(26,187,156)",
        data : [12.500, 11.900, 12.000, 10.100, 12.300, 12.000, 11.200, 10.150, 10.602, 12.000, 12.010, 12.992]
      },


    ]};


    var canvas = document.getElementById('grafica').getContext('2d');

    var canvas2 = document.getElementById('grafica2').getContext('2d');
    window.bar = new Chart(canvas2, FOODATA)


    window.bar = new Chart(canvas, {
      type : "bar",
      data : datos,
      options : {
        elements : {
          rectangle : {
            borderWidth : 1,

            borderSkipped : 'bottom'
          }
        },
        responsive : true,
        title : {
          display : true,
          text : "2017"
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Ahi tendrias el canvas y el canvas2 para poner datos distintos.

Comment: Hola Zeuz, bienvenido. Esto es un comentario, no una respuesta. Deberías esperar a tener 50 de reputacion para poder comentar en cualquier sitio. Mientras tanto, procura responder preguntas que no requieran aclaracion del autor. Un saludo

Comment: Por muy buena que sea tu intencion con esta respuesta, estas respondiendo con un comentario y no con una respuesta.

Comment: La idea era ayudar, se que es un comentario y no una respuesta. Pero nadie le comentaba nada como para poder colaborar. La próxima dejare en blanco la respuesta  a la espera que algún "caritativo" con mas puntos le comente para poder ayudarlo. en fin creo que no hace crecer a la comunidad de stackoverflow en español sumar adeptos si por la mínima intención de ayudar se los califica negativamente. Dicho esto procederé a colaborar con nuestro compañero.

Comment: @zeuz1983 Si crees que ese parece ser el problema, modifica tu _comentario_ para que parezca una respuesta arreglando el problema que tiene el _op_, así tendrá más peso :D

Comment: @NaCl es exactamente lo que hice.

Comment: Muestrale como queda el código luego de arreglarlo y como funciona.

Comment: Después de la edición, esta respuesta es correcta. Tienes mi +1. Entendería si quieres borrar la respuesta y poner otra nueva (aunque no sé si va "contra las reglas"). Si lo haces, te votaré +1 también en la otra.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Mejor es [proveer respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/39887)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro tenes razon ahi agregue codigo.

Comment: @Muriano le solicite mas información para poder ayudarlo como explique mas arriba. Conozco las reglas la intención fue ayudar a un colega. Primera y ultima ayuda en stackoverflow español no te preocupes

Comment: @Muriano ademas de esto, fijate que si funciono en definitiva porque pude ayudarlo. Pero los felicito por ser tan puristas. Me vuelvo a stackoverflow en ingles, mucho mas colaborativo por lo visto.

Comment: @zeuz1983 no te lo tomes como algo personal. Reconozco que la recepción ha sido un poco "brusca", pero la comunidad en general es bastante abierta y con ganas de colaborar. Espero que podamos seguir viéndote por SOes más adelante.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro La gran diferencia que noto entre SO y SOes, básicamente es que acá la gente enseguida le gusta usar sus puntos para hacerse los puristas de las reglas en vez de colaborar. Los mismos que me hacen notar el "error" podían haberle pedido mas info pero no mejor no hacemos nada y criticamos. En SO mi primer pregunta estuvo plagada de "errores" y colegas con muchísimos mas puntos que los anteriores me los marcaron para que los corrija sin hacerse los superados. La primer experiencia aquí no fue buena realmente agradezco sus palabras.

Comment: Lamento que te lo tomes así @zeuz1983. Mi comentario está autogenerado por el sistema, evidentemente la respuesta era de baja calidad. Pero ha servido para que añadas código y mejores su calidad, así que no veo dónde está el problema.

Comment: @Muriano La respuesta ya estaba correcta (Según las normas), alvaro sugirio añadir código de manera amable y así lo hice. La primera vez le pedí mas información porque supuse que no era tan difícil el problema.